# Wp_query not working in wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Am newbie to wordpress i can't understand WP_Query in wordpress,am passing parameter post_status => 'public' means what happend in Wordpress,

```
select * from wp_posts where post_status ='public'
```

I want to write query and show details like above mysql_query.But below my wordpress coding its getting result post_status ='auto_craft',Am so confused why its showing that result but am pass the post_status ='public'

Wordpress:

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'public'
            );
            $post_query = null;
            $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
            var_dump($post_query->request);



            if ($post_query) {

                while ($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
                    echo "fdsfl;dslfgsss";
                    global $post;
                    echo $post->post_title;



                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
            }
            ?>
```

What's wrong in my above coding? in my var_dump i got result like below,

```
"SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC "
```

What is 1 = 1 ? not checking 'post_status' = 'public'

My Customize coding:

```
$post_status = empty($postarr['post_status']) ? 'draft' : $postarr['post_status'];
if ('attachment' === $post_type && in_array($post_status, array('public'))) {
    $post_status = $postarr['post_status'];
} elseif ('attachment' === $post_type && in_array($post_status, array('private_soundcloud'))) {
    $post_status = 'private_soundcloud';
} else {
    if ('attachment' === $post_type && !in_array($post_status, array('inherit', 'private', 'trash'))) {
        $post_status = 'inherit';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass wrong `post_status` value, Can you please replace with

```
'post_status' => 'public'
```

**TO**

```
'post_status' => 'publish'
```

Comment: thanx for your reply,but i having record post_status ='public' in db.

Comment: you have to create custom `post_status` like `public` right ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status),

> Posts in WordPress can have one of a number of statuses. The status of
>   a given post determines how WordPress handles that post. For instance,
>   public posts viewable by everyone are assigned the publish status,
>   while drafts are assigned the draft status. The status is stored in
>   the post_status field in the wp_posts table.

Check [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for understand Class Reference/WP Query.

Comment: thanx for your reply,sry for my silly question,am customize post_status insert value, is it fine or not?plz refer my customize coding inserting post_status?is it possible in wordpress or not?

Comment: Yes this is possible. check this link:- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status

Comment: @geethasj1sj: if your problem is resolved then accept the answer.